# how to run fastq screen in Linux

Tags: screen, fastq

I'm new to the feild and trying to run fastq screen. I have downloads all required packeges for fastq screen.

when I try to run it i get this error.

```
 Reading configuration from '/home/ahmad/FastQ-Screen-0.15.2/fastq_screen.conf'
Aligner (--aligner) not specified. Did not find Bowtie/Bowtie2/BWA paths and/or index files
Please check: you have provided the full path to the aligner INCLUDING the executable filename
Please check: the specified genome indices comprises the full path AND the basename of the index files
See documentation for further details
Please adjust configuration.
```

I opened the fastq_screen.conf and I adjust the path for bowtie2 to be at /usr/bin/bowtie2 /usr/share/man/man1/bowtie2.1.gz

the path for genome ref /home/ahmad/FastQ_Screen_Genomes/Human

but still get the same error. any help please ??

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check your `bowtie2` version:

```
bowtie2 --version
```

And it automatically shows you the pathway you want, which does not end in `.gz`.

Also when you use:

```
fastq_screen --get_genomes
```

The file `fastq_screen.conf` in the `FastQ_Screen_Genomes` folder will have the pathway to your genome files so you only need to change the bowtie2 pathway, copy that file into your `fastq-screen` main folder.